# Difference between old and new formatting options Python

Tags: python

What is the difference between this "Old" type of formatting and the "New" type of formatting?

New:
`'%s %s' % ('one', 'two')`

Old:
`'{} {}'.format('one', 'two')`

Can someone explain this to me? Every example I've tried has given me the same result regardless of either formatting option. Is this just for personal preference? If so that seems kind of wasteful?

EDIT: also what is this? `f'{one} {two}'` as mentioned in the comments....

Comment: and what about the [newnew](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals) `f'{one} {two}'` ?

Comment: the % one is now deprecated. format is way more powerful.

Comment: _Whaaa!_ There's more?!

Comment: python 3.6 only IIRC

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Can you please elaborate?

Comment: the `f` prefix is new in the language. You need python 3.6

Comment: python comes back to its roots ... -> C

Comment: This might help you https://mkaz.tech/code/python-string-format-cookbook/

Comment: @Dharmesh bookmarked thanks!

Comment: :( my question has been downvoted, Sorry I didn't realize there was a question like it.. the way I searched for it didn't make it show

Comment: If this question is duplicate of two other questions does that mean that the two other questions are duplicates of the other? Which ever was made first?